# How to add a line to .bib file?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have an entry like this in the `ref.bib` file

```
@article{nakagawa2018non,
  title={Non-Hermitian Kondo effect in ultracold alkaline-earth atoms},
  author={Nakagawa, Masaya and Kawakami, Norio and Ueda, Masahito},
  journal={Physical review letters},
  volume={121},
  number={20},
  pages={203001},
  year={2018},
  publisher={APS}.
  }
```

Which produces reference like:

> Masaya Nakagawa, Norio Kawakami, and Masahito Ueda. Non-hermitian kondo eect
> in ultracold alkaline-earth atoms. Physical review letters, 121(20):203001, 2018.

How do I add a sentence in the `.bib` file such that it produces:

> Masaya Nakagawa, Norio Kawakami, and Masahito Ueda. Non-hermitian kondo eect
> in ultracold alkaline-earth atoms. Physical review letters, 121(20):203001, 2018. THE SENTENCE ADED HAS TO APPEAR HERE.

Comment: This really depends on the bibliography style that you are using. Many styles support a `note` field for additional text, but that is not guaranteed to come at the end. Most `biblatex` styles have `addendum` which comes towards the end.

Comment: @moewe I was using unsrt. But I can change to whichever supports that. Can you tell me a style that allows me to do it?

Comment: Off-topic: `publisher={APS}.` is a mistake; it should be `publisher={APS},`. The only reason you've likely been able to get away with the mistake until now is because the `unsrt` style simply ignores the `publisher` field for entries of type `@article`.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 5):

How about the following BibTeX entry?

```
@article{nakagawa2018non,
  title =    {Non-{Hermitian} {Kondo} effect in ultracold
                  alkaline-earth atoms},
  author =   {Nakagawa, Masaya and Kawakami, Norio and Ueda,
                  Masahito},
  journal =  {Physical Review Letters},
  volume =   121,
  number =   20,
  pages =    203001,
  year =     2018,
  publisher =    {APS},
  note =     {THE SENTENCE ADED HAS TO APPEAR HERE},
}
```

Below is obtained from `unsrt` style.
[image]

Comment: As a good housekeeping measure, you should also encase the words `Hermitian` and `Kondo` in curly braces, to prevent BibTeX from converting them to all-lowercase.

Comment: @mico, sure. It's done.